# how to Disable special keyboard keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a script or a program that runs in background and blocks special keys on my keyboard (calculator, mute, etc) I have searched a lot on this on the internet but didn't found anything useful or working for me, I tried sharpkeys but didn't detected those keys on my keyboard, key id is 173 for mute on my keyboard and I can get others IDs if I find anything to block them with IDs.

P.S. I don't know much about programming and most likely don't know what I am doing, I'm looking for basic help from anyone. thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**  To disable *all* "special keys" you could change the `Human Interface Device Access` Windows service startup type from `Automatic` to `Manual` (or `Disabled` in case there is some other software installed that causes it to still start when set to `Manual`). **Caution**: this may break other input devices if present, such as [IR remote controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb417079.aspx), or [Airplane mode radio management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128401.aspx).

For background, those "*special keys*" are technically called "*consumer control buttons (CCB)*" (see for example [Keyboard Enhancements in Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn613956.aspx) and the linked `.docx` - nevermind that CCBs long predate Windows 8).

The CCBs are handled by the `Human Interface Device Access` Windows service, as described at [Human Interface Device Access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756979.aspx):

> This service provides generic access to specific functions contained within controls collections on HID (Human Interface Devices). It enables the use of predefined hot buttons on keyboards, remote controls and other multimedia devices.
>
> If the service is stopped or disable, the buttons on USB keyboards will not function (i.e., back, forward, volume up, down, previous track, next track), nor will the volume buttons on USB speakers.

To change the `Human Interface Device Access` (`HidServ`) startup mode, navigate to `My Computer / Manage / Services and Applications / Services`, double-click the `Human Interface Device Access` in the list, and change the `Startup type` to `Manual` or `Disabled`.

Comment: Holy shit thank you soo much! its a bummer that i won't be able to use the media controls but still way better than hitting speaker mute and calculator while playing games. Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess they renamed it to "Human Interface Device Service" now, but this still works like a charm for me :) thanks!

Comment: Thanx @dxiv for this tip. It works almost to perfection. All buttons are disabled BUT the button I accidentally hit now and then while debugging, the one on DELL KB522p that is close to F11, the Sleep button. If I could chose, I would have it the other way around, that I could disable the sleep button only. Is there any way that could be done?

Comment: I found this article that is exactly what I wanted: https://techdows.com/2013/02/disable-sleep-keyboard-button.html

Answer (score 0):

To disable special keyboard keys via registry on Windows 10 go to  HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hidserv and change "Start" DWORD value to 4. Once you restart the system, special function keys should be disabled.